# Наречия: местоимённые или местоименные?

Tags: грамотная-речь, терминология, е-или-ё

Как правильно: *местоимённый* или *местоименный*?

Comment: Артём (можно - по имени?), поменяйте метку на "наречия".

Comment: Да не то слово, Римма, — даже нужно по имени! :) Не люблю "собачек", но иногда приходится их использовать, чтобы нужному человеку пришло уведомление (если для меня самого это важно).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Дело в том, Римма, что я хотел поставить метку "ё-или-е" (как сейчас), а существовала только слитная без разделений. Такую ставить не хотелось, я предложил поменять метку на Мете, и это одобрили. :) Можно было какие-то поставить другие, но вот Aer сделал, как посчитал правильным, теперь — вот и хорошо. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Верно: *местоим**е**нное наречие*. Вариант *местоим**ё**нное наречие* допустим, однако старшая норма именно с *е*.

Источники: http://slovari.ru/search.aspx?s=0&p=3068&di=vmas&wi=29805 и Орфоэпический словарь русского языка под ред. Н. А. Еськовой.

[image: Орфоэпический словарь русского языка под ред. Н. А. Еськовой]

Comment: А что Вы скажете на это: http://lik-bez.com/board/morfologija/narechie/mestoimjonnye_narechija/35-1-0-141? И в словаре Аванесова *местоимённый* значится как дополнительный вариант: http://slovarina.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0256.htm.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой это допустимо, но старшая норма именно *местоим**е**нный*. Дополню ответ.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо! И всё-таки меня радует, что и через Ё можно говорить это слово. ;)

Comment: А скрин откуда? Из Еськовой этой? Кто-то на неё недавно ссылался... 2010 г. ещё помню, если ничего не перепутал...

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой из словаря Еськовой (как раз переработанный Аванесовский).

Comment: А переработан он с учётом изменений временнЫх или просто какие-то недочёты исправлены (если они были)?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой как отмечают авторы, речь идет о "коренной переработке", т. е. словарь был актуализирован (уточнены рекомендации и обновлен словник), были доработаны принципы его устройства (с учетом последних научных достижений) и т. д., и т. п.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо! Кстати, мне уведомление почему-то не пришло о Вашем сообщении, хотя вроде Вы всё оформили правильно для этого. Странно(